# Google sheets formula to sumif within other sheets in the workbook, without writing out the sheet name, instead using reference/contents column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a googlesheet (sheet 1) which looks like this:
contents contains a column with Months

```
May 2021
June 2021
July 2021
August 2021
September 2021
October 2021
November 2021
December 2021
January 2022
February 2022
March 2022
April 2022
May 2022
June 2022
```

Each month / cell in column A (sheet 1) all link to another sheet within the workbook containing the data for each month, all data has different rows, so to summarise each month, I want a formula like this:

```
=sumif(indirect(A4,&"!A:A"),"ProductA",(indirect(A&"!B:B")))
```

where A4 references January 2021, and this is linked to sheet January 2021, **ProductA** is in column A of each monthly breakdown (all sheets after sheet 1), and the number of these in column B.
I want to be able to drag this formula down, and have the sheet look for the sum of **ProductA** across all months, using Column A in sheet 1 to reference the sheet it should look in, i.e. the month.

Does this make any sense?
I can add more info, apologies for the waffle.

Sheet 2 for example contains Month1 data and looks like this:
Category (Ticket)   Count   Thread  Time
prod1   5   22  8395:35:00
prod2   67  5411    644:24:00
prod3   544 55  18283:24:00
prod4   56  546546  97093:52:00
prod5   75  646 38238:11:00

Comment: Formatting went wrong, but column A sheet 1 contains all months going down

Comment: Would you be able to include a copy of the spreadsheet you are using so we can get a better idea of the structure/setup?

Comment: Or I can make a public copy and link it, this would be an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fqaIg-bqKKSwN_ZX9sYG3Aj2NdHvR0xPnc07MCNlbME/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a formula that should work for you:

`=arrayformula(sumif(indirect($A2&"!A:A"),C$1,(indirect($A2&"!B:B"))))`

You can place this into cell `C2`, and then copy it down and across.

The issue with your formula was first that you had `(indirect(A&"!B:B"))`, instead of `(indirect(A2&"!B:B"))`.
Secondly, you need to make sure that there's no extra space after your values.

[image]
In the above image, you have an extra space after `prod3`, so when using the `SUMIF` and trying to match the value, it was not working. If something is resulting in `0` where it shouldn't be, make sure to check that first. I have found that `prod4` and `prod6` both have the same issue.

---

[image]

Comment: Kaitlunmm569 you're amazing thank you! (The spaces were all because I renamed those cells on the fly to create the test and protect the names of real products). The solution works perfectly Thank you!